# Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql

Tags: apt, apache2, mysql, 15.10

Trying to install this package on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql`, but I get the message in the title. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using is 15.10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package has been deleted in [Ubuntu 15.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-auth-mysql/+publishinghistory) (since it was deleted [upstream in Debian 8](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788638)). The module itself is [apparently unmaintained](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/05/msg00694.html), and [`mod_authn_dbd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) or [`mod_authz_dbd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_dbd.html) should be used instead.

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server mod_authn_dbd php7.0-mysql    is giving the following error.  E: Unable to locate package mod_authn_dbd
How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

From here: [phpmyadmin not working due to missing mbstring extention](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760567/phpmyadmin-missing-mbstring-extention-ubuntu-16-04)

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
sudo service apache2 restart
```