# phpmyadmin not working due to missing mbstring extention

Tags: apache2, 16.04, phpmyadmin

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. But my phpmyadmin has error

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I searched somewhere but no solution on Ubuntu. Please help me.
I'm using apache2